# Inheritance rules in MDriven?

Tags: mdriven

I have a case where the designer allows me to set inheritance from one class (no inheritance) towards a superclass but not towards that superclass subclasses? Why would that not be allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We disallow inheritance from classes marked with IsSealed, and also if class is an association class.